# Vue Js child to parent custom event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I'm actually struggling quite a bit about transmitting info between a child component to a parent component in a  Vue-js-2 cli project.

So I have a popup modal that appears when a data is true
`<component v-if="profile" />`
this popup contains my child component (a profile page) now how Am I supposed to be able to close this popup ?
I added a little "cross icon" in it so I need on a **click event** to say to the parent that `this.profile = false`

I'm sure that I need to do it in a $emit event but don't understand how to modify a data from parent in a custom child event...
thanks for any help !

Comment: Consider posting a [mre] code post with your question to help us fully understand it *and* reproduce it. Please check out the link to this valuable tool so that you consider using it in the future even if you don't for this question.

Comment: But all you have to do is handle the child's emit event in the parent, something well explained in the Vue tutorials: [Emitting and Listening to Events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events). Again, how is your code attempt at this not working? Please show it.

Comment: Now if the child is nested a few components deep, you may want to use the inject / provide mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to accomplish what you need:

#### Option 1: v-model

You can refer to [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html?redirect=true#Customizing-Component-v-model)

```
<component v-model="value">
```

This is equivalent to (in most cases)

```
<component v-bind:value="data" v-on:change="data = $event">
```

#### Option 2: v-bind:value.sync

How [sync modifier of v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html?redirect=true#sync-Modifier) achieves two-way data transmission.
But in fact, these expressions are syntax sugar for event processing.

```
<component v-bind:value.sync="data">
```

equivalent to

```
<component v-bind:value="data" v-on:update:value="data = $event">
```

Comment: So you mean In the parent I have a data variable declared ` myData: false` and in the child I have the same data declared again ? I can't refer to `myData` in the child if it's not declared in right ?

Comment: If you don't need to watch the state in the child component, you can omit v-bind and only change the state of the parent component in event processing. Like: `<component v-on:event-name="data = $event">`.